# Массив или куча переменных

Tags: массивы, переменные, php, оптимизация

Как лучше хранить однотипные данные: в массиве или пачке переменных? Например сохранять настройки:

```
$setting_limit = 5;
$setting_quantity = 5;
```

Или же

```
$setting['limit'] = 5;
$setting['quantity'] = 5;
```

Comment: В массиве.

Comment: Настройки нужно хранить НЕ в коде, а в отдельных файлах. Хардкодить данные - плохо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С массивом есть много преимуществ.

- при добавлении нового параметра не нужно переписывать код сохранения параметров.
- очень легко написать код заворачивания настроек в удобный формат (ini, json, xml).
- удобно делать отладочную распечатку.

но есть и минусы:

- очень легко ошибиться в одну букву и потом долго искать ошибку (но можно завести константы).
- приходиться аккуратнее писать документацию по переменным, так как они разбросаны по коду.
- можно легко испортить, а искать потом по коду, где это - может быть очень сложно.

хороший способ - хранить настройки массивом, завести константы для всех настроек, возле констант проставить коментарии о их назначении. Для особых настроек завести специальные методы чтения/записи и хранить отдельным массивом, что бы не попортить.

Comment: Речь идет не только о настройках, а об однотипных данных: данные переданные через POST и обработанные, данные с базы данных и так далее.

Comment: "однотипные данные" уже говорит о том, что нужно использовать массив (или хэш).

Answer (score 0):

Файл [ini](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php) или файл с JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Массив. Более гибко.

Answer (score 0):

Хранить надо так, как удобнее использовать.

Удобнее разные переменные - значит надо использовать разные переменные, и не важно, какого они типа. В большинстве случаев это более естественный вариант.

Удобнее массив, например, для обращения по ключу из переменной и для перебора ключей - надо использовать массив.